# 09 is not recognized where as 9 is recognized

Tags: java, integer, octal

I am using quartz for schedulling.

```
TriggerUtils.getDateOf(0,40,18,09,06);
```

it accept 5 parameter. (seconds, minutes, hours, daysOfMonth, month).

When i pass fourth parameter as "09". Eclipse give me error "The literal Octal 09 (digit 9) of type int is out of range ".

**But when i pass the fourth parameter as "9" instead of "09", it works.**

Can anyone explain me this error?

Comment: You realize that the integers 06 and 6 are the same thing, right?

Comment: @matt: He's passing a date into the function, and not realizing that a preceding 0 turns it to an octal number.

Comment: if i can pass 25, then why not 09.

Comment: I think we've all been bitten by that one once or twice. I think in 30 years of programming I've intentionally used octal once (and binary and hexadecimal countless times). Octal's favored states is truly a throwback.

Comment: @Shashi: 25 is a number. 0 before a number signals that you want to use octal, so you're going into a different numbering system. Only applies to 0 because you normally drop the 0.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In java, if you are defining an integer, a leading '0' will denote that you are defining a number in octal

```
int i = 07; //integer defined as octal
int i = 7; // integer defined as base 10
int i = 0x07; // integer defined as hex
int i = 0b0111; // integer defined as binary (Java 7+)
```

Comment: I didn't know about "0b". Does that work in C, too?

Comment: The 0b prefix doesn't exist yet; it's a possible extension to Java 7.

Answer (score 20):

There is no 9 in [Octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) (what you get with a preceding 0).  0-7, only.

Answer (score 13):

When you precede a number with 0 ("09" rather than "9"), then Java (and C and many other languages) interpret the number to be in octal - base-8.

"09" is not a valid number in octal - any single digit can be a maximum of "7" (since in octal, numbers go from 0..7).

Answer (score 11):

Numbers that begin with the zero digit are treated as octal (base 8) literals, and 9 is not a valid octal digit.

Answer (score 3):

**10** is how many digits you have, whereas **010** is is what you get if you don't count your thumbs.