# How to store '09' in integer

Tags: java

I am working on a java program and I need to store some integers starting from 0 to 16 as 
00, 01 and so on...

Now when I store '09' for 9 or '08' for 8 it starts giving me error.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970039/09-is-not-recognized-where-as-9-is-recognized)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218760/why-is-08-not-a-valid-integer-literal-in-java) question I know that it is octal notation.

My question is :

IS there a way to store 08 or 09 in integer in JAVA?

I HAVE to store numbers as 00, 01 .. only what is alternative?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you need it in this format? For output or something else?

Comment: What situation do you want to use 00, 01 etc. in?

Comment: It is unlikely you need to *store* them like that, you probably need to *display* them like that - is that fair?

Comment: You'ld have to use `System.out.printf()` to format output, but you can't use it internally as "08", "09", etc.

Comment: No! I want to use these integers later on That is why I am storing them as integers, otherwise I would have used String

Comment: @Nullpointer: In what way do you think that 08 is different to 8, in terms of integer values?

Comment: leading 0 is not part of the number, it is part of the formating.

Comment: When I print the values I need 09 but I also need to do some integral manipulation on those Hence I can not store them as Strings(I don't want to use Integer.ParseInt(String) everytime)

Comment: Write a print or toString method to handle printing your ints the way you want...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Store your numbers with an Integer, and if you need to display these values cast them in a String. The String could be easily format to show the leading zero.

```
    int num = 5;
    System.out.println(String.format("%02d", num));
```

Comment: Storing it in a string might not be the best approach.

Comment: You can replace the word "storing" with "casting" ;)

Comment: no need to store it as a string..

Comment: Not good enough - what with 10-16? Should you propose something with formating the value.

Comment: Though none of you understood my real problem(people are just throwing negative votes without even reading the problem completely) and none of the solutions given was perfect to my needs; I think this is the most relevant solution so I am accepting this!

Comment: Integer is just the Autoboxed Object of the primitive int type. Ok, it's no cast, you're right.

Comment: For real number what is the format for, eg: 09.23

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do it unless you store them as string. 
Or store them as regular int and use string format for the output.

Answer (score 2):

It just makes no sense to try to store `09` as a numeric value (unless you really mean `9` in octal, which would make even less sense). The `09` value you're referring to is *a representation* of the value `9`. Numeric values don't have anything to do with how they are represented. You could represent the value *nine* in decimal base as `9` or `09` or `9.0`, or in octal base as `011`, but the value remains the same, *nine*, and it should be stored in an `Integer` variable (or an `int`).

Store the numbers in `Integer` variables as the numeric values they are, and output them with the format you wish to with [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) for instance:

```
 Integer i = 9; // or Integer i = 011; whatever
 System.out.println(String.format("%02d", i));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

```
int num = 9;
System.out.println(String.format("%02d", num));
```

In `%02d`

- `0` - to pad with zeros
- `2` - to set width to 2

*Output*

```
09
```

Comment: For real number what is the format for, eg: 09.23

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to do something wrong; there are a number of possible ways however.

Case 1: You are trying to store a date component and display it as two digits. In this case, use [`java.util.Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) instead.

Case 2: You are trying to store part of a version number. In this case, you should be storing it as a `String`, not an `int`.

Case 3: You are trying to store some other type of data, and need to display it with a leading zero. For this, you should be using [`PrintStream.printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf) or [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) bto do this. `System.out.printf("%1$2d", myInteger)` will output the number as two digits, adding a leading zero if needed.