# Java: Using "08" and "09" in an array

Tags: java, arrays

How can I store 08 and 09 into an int array? I understand that they cannot due to binary characteristics and have tried both...

0b08, 0b09 ... and ... 0B08, 0B09 with no luck.

The following line of code is ideally what I'd like to have:

```
final int[] monthValidDosInputs = {00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12};
```

Here is the error...

```
ConvertDate.java:15: error: integer number too large: 08
ConvertDate.java:15: error: integer number too large: 09
```

Thanks!

Comment: You don't want to store numbers but strings. Use `String[]` and add quotes around your literals.

Comment: You're saying use strings to store all values? 00-12?

Comment: That works... but is there a way to represent both 08 and 09 as ints?

Comment: Or better, don't store anything, just build the strings when needed. Why do you have such an array ?

Comment: The integer `08` is the same than `8`.

Comment: Each number represents the month number Jan-Dec...1-12

Comment: I need both 08 and 8 to be valid inputs, cannot just store 8 solely

Comment: How do you use this array ? You should probably use a [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: you can use simply 1-12 why you need o to be prepended.?

Comment: Upon entering date values, some users may be inclined to enter "08" rather than just "8"

Comment: The integer 08 is NOT the same as 8. Try printing 010 just to find out. If you try printing 08 as it is, you will get an error without defining that its a double before printing `System.out.println(08D)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [09 is not recognized where as 9 is recognized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970039/09-is-not-recognized-where-as-9-is-recognized)

Answer (score 13):

When you start a literal integer with `0`, it's considered an *octal* number, one that uses base 8 rather than base 10. That means `8` and `9` are not valid digits.

If you *really* want a leading zero (i.e., octal), you would need something like:

```
int[] monthValidDosInputs = {000, 001, ..., 007, 010, 011, 012, 013, 014};
```

which gives you the decimal numbers `0` through `12`, but in octal.

However, if you want to keep them evenly spaced with decimal, just use a leading space instead of zero:

```
int[] monthValidDosInputs = { 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12};
//                           ^^  ^^  ^^  ^^  ^^  ^^  ^^  ^^  ^^  ^^  ^^  ^^  ^^
```

although I'm not sure you gain anything from that. You may as well just use:

```
int[] monthValidDosInputs = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
```

and be done with it. It makes no difference to the compiler.

---

If you're looking to use these to check user input (where they may enter `8` or `08` for a month), you're better off either:

- using strings to check against; or
- reducing their input to an integer (using something like `Integer.parseInt(str,10)`) so that there's no difference between `04` and `4`.

Comment: @assylias, yes, you're correct, I've changed the octal values so they _all_ have a leading zero. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

dystroy is right, store them as strings in a `String[]` array and then parse them to `int` when you want to use them as integers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way I know of that you can hold those values in and int[] array. 
Instead use String[] array and convert to int values if needed.