# Convert int which start with leading zero to string

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert int's which start with 0 to strings to be stored in a phone directory as the telephone numbers can start with 0.

I've tried -

```
int num = 0125;
String.format("%04d",num);
```

and

```
Integer.toString(num);
```

and

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0000");
df.format(num);
```

Each time I get the output `0085` rather than `0125`.

How do I convert an int with a leading zero to a string in decimal format?

Comment: There is no `int` that starts with leading zero. The number is *octal*.

Comment: A phone "number" isn't a number, its a word. Use the string class to hold it (or a special purpose PhoneNumber class)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An `int` value starting with a zero is considered to be a `octal number` (having numbers from 0 - 7) similar to hexadecimal numbers. Hence your value:

```
0125
```

is equal to: **1 * 8<sup>2</sup> + 2 * 8<sup>1</sup> + 5 * 8<sup>0</sup> == 64 + 16 + 5 == 85**

Don't try to represent a phone-number as an `int`. Instead use a `String` and validate it using a regex expression. If you combine both, you may as well represent a phone number by its own type like:

```
public class PhoneNumber {

    private final String number;

    public PhoneNumber(String number) {
        if (number == null || !number.matches("\\d+([-]\\d+)?")) {
            throw new .....
        }
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

The `regex` is just an example matching phone numbers like: `1234` or `0123-45678`.

Answer (score 1):

A numeric literal that starts with `0` is considered to be Octal (base 8). 125 base 8 is 85 base 10 (decimal).

Also, `int i = 09` will throw a compiler error for the same reason.

See [09 is not recognized where as 9 is recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970039/09-is-not-recognized-where-as-9-is-recognized)

Answer (score 1):

`0125` is actually 85. Why?

Numbers that starts with 0, are *octal* numbers. So 0125 is:

5*8<sup>0</sup> + 2*8<sup>1</sup> + 1*8<sup>2</sup> = 85

See the [JLS - 3.10.1. Integer Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1):

> An octal numeral consists of an ASCII digit 0 followed by one or more
>   of the ASCII digits 0 through 7 interspersed with underscores, and can
>   represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.