# Addition of numbers - output

Tags: java, addition

I could not understand the exact computation logic here. How is `01234` being treated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(01234 + 43210);
    System.out.println(1234 + 43210);
}
```

Output

```
43878
44444
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [09 is not recognized where as 9 is recognized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970039/09-is-not-recognized-where-as-9-is-recognized)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is 01234 being treated?

It is treated here as octal. Any number starting with `0` is octal.

Answer (score 3):

A number literal starting with a leading zero is treated as octal (base 8).
So `01234` is in fact `668 (decimal)`