# default format for byte data type

Tags: java, byte

I was just doing a task about retrieving the bits from a byte. When I was just retrieving a byte I was getting wrong results. For a byte

```
byte b = (byte) 00000011;
```

the retrieved bits were in the order

```
00001001
```

After observation I found that the compiler interprets the value

```
byte b = (byte) 00000011;
System.out.println(b); //value comes as 9
```

so when retrieving it gives its binary equivalent which is `00001001` which is correct, can anyone suggest why the compiler interprets the value as 9? What is the default format of a byte?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The literal `00000011` is an [octal integer literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970039/09-is-not-recognized-where-as-9-is-recognized) in Java, in this case octal 11, which is equivalent to 9 in decimal. Use `0b00000011` (with a `0b` instead of `0` prefix) to make a binary literal.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the interpreter treats every single 0 or 1 as a multiple of 8; so, `00000011` is 8 + 1 = 9. `00000101` comes out to 65.

Related: [09 is not recognized where as 9 is recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970039/09-is-not-recognized-where-as-9-is-recognized?lq=1)

Comment: *"it appears the interpreter treats every single 0 or 1 as a multiple of 8"*, because a number that starts with a **0** is treated as an [*octal value*](http://rodrigosasaki.com/2013/06/10/number-literals-in-java/).